# Clone m.2 drive windows boot drive

Tags: windows, nvme, m.2

I am looking for a free way to clone the contents of an existing drive to a larger one.

I would like to replace the current drive with a new one 4 times larger and have it boot windows without reinstalling.

How would I go about cloning my existing drive and make the new one just boot?

Comment: AOMEI, Acronis, Macrium ...  there are a number.  "Free" and top quality needed for cloning tend to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Many SSDs come with software to do just that.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This is a question asking for a software recommendation, and we don't do that here as it attracts opinion based answers. If you really need a software recommendation, you may have more luck over on the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DarkDiamond I don't think this is about software alone, OP is specifically asking for the procedure.

Comment: @mashuptwice well, if that's  the case, then I misunderstood the question, but nevertheless this question attracts opinion based answers.

Answer (score 1):

I will only use Linux as I am used to it, if someone has a better way using other tools feel free to add an answer.

You can only clone your boot drive if it is not mounted. For this you will need to create a bootable USB drive with Rufus. You will need either a second m.2 slot in your PC or an external case to connect your new drive while you are copying the data. Note that this process will only work as-is if there is no encryption in place.

0. Backup your data. This is the most important step.
1. Download Rufus from [Github](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases)
2. Download SystemRescue from [their Website](https://www.system-rescue.org/Download/)
3. Connect an empty USB Stick with a minimum of 4gb of storage to your PC, note that any files on it will be erased
4. Start Rufus **as Administrator** and select your USB, the Systemrescue-x.xx-amd64.iso you've downloaded and click Start. Wait for the process to complete.

[image: Rufus]

5. **Shutdown** your computer, boot into the boot menu and select the USB you've just created. You might need to enable legacy boot and the bootmenu in your BIOS settings.
6. Select the first entry and press enter on Systemrescues boot menu. [image: systemrescue grub]
7. Type "startx", press enter and wait for the GUI to load.

[[image: startx5]

8. Click on the little black icon on the lower left to open a terminal window

[image: terminall]

9. In the window which opens type "lsblk" to show all connected drives, your drive descriptors may vary. I will use sda as the current smaller drive and sdb as the new bigger drive.
   [image: lsblk]

9.1. We will use dd to write the data from one drive to the other, bit by bit. You need to make absolutely sure that you don't mix up the input and the output drive, as otherwise your data will be overwritten with 0s from your new, empty drive! Make sure you identified your drives in the previous step without any doubt before continuing! If you are using an external enclosure you can disconnect it and run lsblk again, the drive which disappeared is obviously the one you've disconnected.

10. Clone your harddrive with dd: `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress bs=4M && sync` where `if` is the input device and `of` is the output device. You will need to use the identifiers for your drives instead of sda and sdb obviously. Wait patiently until the process has finished.

[image: dd]

11. When finished, you will notice that your new drive now has the exact same partition structure as your old one. Now we will resize and expand the partition to be able to use all of the storage space. Remember your "main" partitions number for the following steps. In my case it is sdb2.

[image: same structure]

12. You'll want to run `ntfsfix /dev/sdb2` to make sure your filesystem is clean before the next step.
13. Start `parted` in terminal and type `select /dev/sdb` to select your new SSD. Type `print` to get an overview over your partitions. You'll want to work with the last, probably biggest partition, in my case "2".

[image: parted print]

14. Type `resizepart` then `2` then `100%. Let parted finish its job. The partition now should take the maximum amount of availible space on the device.

[image: resizepart]

15. Now type `quit`
16. Run `ntfsfix /dev/sdb` again, just to be sure.

You're done at this point.

17. As a last command type `poweroff`
18. Swap your drives and boot windows.

Disclaimer: I don't take any responsibility for user error, data loss, nuclear war, or anyone getting Covid after following this guide.

I also don't want to participate in any *nix vs *do(w)s flamewars, if you do have a better solution, please feel free to share it.